# Les isométriques

Tags: vocabulaire, biologie, santé-et-médecine, physique

Il s'agit d'une boîte de films radiographiques (qui ont servi à effectuer un examen radiographique dans une centrale) dont le couvercle porte « les numéros du ou des isométriques concernés ou numéro de l'appareil ».

Savez-vous de quels isométriques il est question ?

Comment: Cette question ne me semble pas concerner la langue française. J'imagine que le sens d'*isométrique* pour désigner ce type de graphique est connu, et que le problème n'est pas là, si ?

Comment: Justement, le sens du terme "isométrique" dans ce contexte ne me paraît pas très clair. Est-ce le plan qui est isométrique ? Ou bien quelque autre élement...?

Comment: Probablement rien à voir, mais si on me dit « film » et « ISO » dans la même phrase, je comprends [Sensibilité ISO](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensibilité_ISO). Quelqu’un aurait-il fait un excès de zèle en « désabréviant » ISO comme isométrique ? Je ne sais même pas si cela a un sens de parler de sensibilité ISO en radiographie.

Comment: Une autre possibilité, peut-être vaguement plus crédible, les radiographies correspondent à des vues représentées par des plans en perspective isométrique. On aura indiqué à quel plan correspond quel film.

Answer (score 3):

D'après la [définition (C) d'isométrique](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/isom%C3%A9trique), je dirais que ces films ont été produits par un [myographe](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/myographe), appareil destiné à l'étude des mouvements et contractions des muscles.

Answer (score 2):

Quitte à deviner, je pense qu'il s'agit du nom [*une isométrique*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/isom%C3%A9trique) et pas de l'adjectif:

> (Sciences) Ligne ou surface sur laquelle une grandeur est constante.

Il s'agit d'*iso* plus *métrique* au sens « mesure », comme dans *radiométrie*, et pas forcément « distance ». C'est quasi-synonyme d'*isoplèthe*, *isoligne* ou *isarithme* (même valeur, même nombre).

Parmi les autres *iso*, le cas qu'on rencontre le plus fréquemment est surement celui des *isohypses*, couramment appelées « courbes de niveau » ou « lignes d'altitude constante » sur une carte. Mais il y a aussi *isobares*, *isothermes*, *isochrones*, *isorades* (radioactivité), etc. Voir la liste des [Iso](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Iso) sur Wikipédia.

Par extension *une isométrique* peut désigner un document qui contient ces courbes.